# Download stops with no msg

Tags: downloading

I'm trying to get apps and I have plenty of storahe but about half a second after download starts it stops with no message

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, maybe you could not have connection on the Internet or broadband on your mobile device. But please give more information. I hope it helps.